# \ (backslash) namespace separator: is it safe to remove?

Tags: php, oop

I got this line of code while integrating Stripe

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_3XdTlKsLkd7encNFZcUfSp6s");
```

Problem is that my server throws an error

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 on line 53

I can remove the \Stripe \ but is it safe to do so? Can it cause any type of conflict down the road?

I know this is related to PHP 5.3, I'm running php 5.2.17 and can't upgrade it unfortunately

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Hi, it's version 5.2.17.

Comment: i'm also pretty new here, could someone explain why the question is getting downvoted? Like that I can avoid this in the future.

Comment: It's being downvoted because you didn't provide a lot of data to go on (that you're running 5.2 is a fairly important piece of information). As it stands, it's likely to get closed because it's not helpful

Comment: ok got it, will keep in mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces were [added to PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php)

> Support for namespaces has been added.

You'll have to upgrade PHP to use namespaces or remove them from your code.

Comment: thank you, as a follow up, is it there any security risk if the namespaces are removed?

Comment: If security is your big thing you should note that 5.2 contains numerous security holes that have never been patched (and never will be). Removing a namespace is not really a security problem, especially in light of that